# setOnClickListener RecycleView (in a Fragment) navigate to another Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have `RecycleView` in `Fragment`. When I click one of the items in `RecyclerView`, I want to open new `Fragment`. The second `Fragment` did not replace the previous but the `Fragment` is overwritten
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDWVF.png). How can I fix this?

My adapter:

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the
        // contents of the view with that element

            val currentProduct = productList[position]

            holder.image.setImageBitmap(currentProduct.image)
            holder.title.text = currentProduct.title
            holder.price.text = currentProduct.price.toString()+"€"



            //Go to product details
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val activity = it.context as AppCompatActivity
                val detailsFragment = ProductDetailsFragment()
                activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,detailsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()
            }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use navigation component and smoothly navigateTo(action_from1fragment_to2fragment).

If you want to open specific dialog, fragment with specific data you can use lambda in adapter to provide id to viewmodel, fragment.

Comment: I can use navigation component but the problem is that I use two times the recycleview in different fragments. eg: profilepage->details and product ->details

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Maybe it's just workaround but try this.
 binding.recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
and all that need to be GONE on that visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Simple ans is to add `elevation` and `background color` to parent layout of second fragment and set arguments like `clickable` and `focusable` to `true`.
your `onClick` for `recyclerView` is working fine.